# Запятая или тире в БСП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп

На месте () следует поставить запятую или тире? Предложение:

> В Терентеево замечательный широкий лес () там много грибов и ягод.

Comment: Употребимо широкое поле, широкая река, но широкий лес?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это описание местности, то лучше использовать запятую, а то при постановке тире или двоеточия получится, что лес замечателен только грибами и ягодами.

Если это путеводитель для грибников, то пояснительные отношения лучше обозначить, допустим, с помощью тире. Тогда на названии "Терентеево" делается логическое ударение, и второе предложение присоединяется к первому.

Примечание. А что значит широкий лес? Может быть, широколиственный. А то есть Широкий лес — заповедное урочище. Находится в Александровском районе Донецкой области возле села Елизаветовка.

Comment: Спасибо, София! Значит если я ставлю тире, то значит я как бы объясняю почему лес замечательный. Он замечательный, так как там есть грибы и ягоды. 

А в случае с запятой как происходит? Я говорю, что лес замечательный, а помимо того, что он замечательный, в нем есть еще грибы и ягоды. Так?

Вы написали "при постановке тире или двоеточия". Вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, объяснить в чем будет различие между тире и двоеточием в данном примере? Я понимаю, что они будут нести разный смысл. 

А по поводу широкий, я имела ввиду - большой. Видимо неудачно выразилась.

Comment: При постановке запятой получается повествование с перечислительной интонацией:"В Терентеево замечательный широкий лес, (в частности) там много грибов и ягод", это как бы одна их примечательных особенностей этого леса. Пояснительные отношения могут передавать  двоеточие (классический вариант) и тире (пояснение в добавочном сообщении). В устной речи варианты различаются по длительности паузы (при двоеточии пауза больше, она предупреждает о пояснении). Можете использовать любой вариант, проверив его на слух.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь!